# android check internet connection best place to call function

Tags: android

with this function i check if there is internet network connection,i call this function in `oncreate()` method.If there is no internet connection when i start the app i show alert and "OK" button, when ok button is pressed i close the application.If internet connection is going down after the user start the app alert is not showing anymore!The questions is,where is the best place to call the function to check the internet all the time,on start app and even after the app was started!It's ok to call twice,oncreate() and onresume() method?

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Comment: Add network check before making any network call. Say before fetching data from API.

Comment: In this case you should check the http response code. if internet connection down during http request after certain time you will get response code. then you decide what you will do depends on response code. Most provably Connection down response code is 503.

Comment: not the expected answers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is some sort of method to monitor for changes in connectivity while the app is running.

This is a common problem and there are simple solutions that already exist within the Android framework to cope with the challenge.

I think the simplest solution is to utilise a broadcast receiver to listen for broadcasts from the ConnectivityManager. From the Android Developer reference ["Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status"](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html):

> The ConnectivityManager broadcasts the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE") action whenever the connectivity details have changed. You can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest to listen for these changes and resume (or suspend) your background updates accordingly.

There's much more information at the provided link. In your case, of course, you might not be managing background updates, but the fundamental problem being solved is the same.